# MediaRecorder : IOexception prepare failed error . Help me please

Tags: java, android, media

Oh.. i always have error in prepare (of mediarecorder). Error  tell me what prepare failed
i can't record not audio, not video ((
/*

```
 ERROR/audio_input(34): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
02-02 12:59:04.813: ERROR/audio_input(34): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
```

*/
this error what always i have ((( Please can anyone help me.. i realy need help. How to fix this. I tested many examples.. i watch many post's here - but nothing not help me. 
Guys - Help please :(((( 
Regards, Peter. 
p.s. sorry for my bad english - hope you understand me.

```
02-02 12:59:04.623: DEBUG/dalvikvm(9334): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4 objects / 307296 bytes in 69ms
02-02 12:59:04.813: ERROR/audio_input(34): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
02-02 12:59:04.813: ERROR/audio_input(34): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
02-02 12:59:04.833: ERROR/CameraInput(34): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
02-02 12:59:04.833: ERROR/CameraInput(34): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
02-02 12:59:04.873: WARN/AuthorDriver(34): Video encoding bit rate is set to 320000 bps
02-02 12:59:04.933: INFO/MediaRecorderJNI(9334): prepare: surface=0x20fad8 (id=1)
02-02 12:59:04.943: ERROR/PVOMXEncNode(34): PVMFOMXEncNode-Audio_AMRNB::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.PV.amrencnb handle 
02-02 12:59:04.973: ERROR/CameraInput(34): Camera is not available
02-02 12:59:04.973: ERROR/AuthorDriver(34): Command 13 completed with error -1
02-02 12:59:04.983: ERROR/MediaRecorder(9334): prepare failed: -1
02-02 12:59:06.273: DEBUG/dalvikvm(9334): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 201 objects / 319048 bytes in 190ms
```

yeah, sorry forgot about code  : code here
function :

```
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private File file = null;
    static final String PREFIX = "record";
    static final String EXTENSION = ".3gpp";
    private void startRecording() throws Exception {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            if (file == null) {
                File rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                file = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, EXTENSION, rootDir);
            }
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
            Log.i("Start","RECORD STARTED");
        }
```

so.. i never see message("record started") in logcat ((,if add videosurse and videoencode - i have error in IOException - prepare failed.  I always have erros  and can't find anything what can help me to solved this problem :( . I read more post's about it - and more guys have too problem.. but other guys - have not problem and all be ok.
Now im try only record audio - my emulator is handsup, and in logcat i see only erros what i write before function code. :'(

oh.. android v 2.2 im programming in exclipse galileo

red colors of errors only here :

```
02-03 13:36:22.783: ERROR/audio_input(34): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
02-03 13:36:22.783: ERROR/audio_input(34): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
02-03 13:36:23.004: ERROR/PVOMXEncNode(34): PVMFOMXEncNode-Audio_AMRNB::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.PV.amrencnb handle 
02-03 13:36:23.073: ERROR/AudioFlinger(34): Error reading audio input
```

**p.s. edited :** After updating eclipse and android sdk (all patch's and other function which aviable for downloads. My camera on "all" emulators work perfectly . I can test record/capture photo/ just review on camera. One minus -  if bug with preview (green lines or other similar ) than this not showing in emulator. But  bugs with rotation ( when on preview all ok and than click on capture or record video we can see what our screen rotated on 90  degree) can be fixed. Hope it's help :)

Comment: can you please put some code that raised this error, so that some one can help

Comment: shouldn't it be `.3gp` ?

Comment: it make no sense : 3gp , 3gpp, mp4 or mp3 . File is created but he always have 0bytes.

Comment: ok after million test's  - this code work for audio . Emulator just is handsup, but when i running in real device i can reccord my voice. So .. for audio reccord it's work...  but for video is not work :|  Hope this comment help someone

Comment: hmmmm, didn't help that much. did you release the audio hardware after testing, like `recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused`. but i guess, you did. please provide more code...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just do as per this it works fine

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: woow!! what an answer.. :/ meh